# Restrict RDP port based on a Dynamic DNS

Tags: networking, firewall, remote-desktop, windows-firewall

I want to set a restriction on my firewall (windows firewall on windows 2008) to only allow connections from a certain dynamic DNS. Is this possible?

The reason I ask is that this would allow us to just change the IP on the dynamic DNS if our IP changes and means we won't get locked out of RDP. This also allows me to RDP in from other locations that have IP's that are not static by just changing the IP against the DNS.

Any ideas.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have created a program that will create the firewall rules based on out DNS instead. This has solved this for us.

Comment: Any more details about how you did this or the approach you took would be really useful. I'm trying to achieve the same thing.

Comment: How did you do this? Will you share your program? I'm trying to accomplish the same thing as well.

Comment: I will try and dig it out for you guys. It's written in delphi though but I'll get the main points.